# How to find which word has max occurance in three fields of a table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

i have a table which has many fields but i want to get count of every word in any three fields of that table

find all title in a table that exist more than once...so for that i can issue this statement

```
SELECT title, COUNT(title) AS NumOccurrences FROM users
GROUP BY titleHAVING ( COUNT(title) > 1 )
```

suppose my table has three fields called **title,url,description**.
basically i do not know which word has been stored in which 3 fields in that table maximum time.

i want to issue a sql statement which can show me which word found maximum time...like

```
word-name          occurance
---------          -------
sqlserver           300
jquery              120
ajax                110
```

please guide me with sample sql for sql server 2000/2005 thanks

### Here is my updated full code.....please have look

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempSearch') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #tempSearch
END

CREATE TABLE #tempSearch(
    ID INT,
    Title nvarchar(4000),
    Description ntext,
    Url nvarchar(4000),
    Type char(1))

INSERT INTO #tempSearch 
    SELECT * from vwProductSearch

INSERT INTO #tempSearch 
    SELECT * from vwContentSearch

    SELECT  Word, 
    COUNT(Word) AS TotalOccurrences,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Title' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInTitle,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'URL' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInURL,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Description' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInDescription
    FROM    (   SELECT  CONVERT(NTEXT, Title) AS Word, 'Title' AS Field
        FROM    #tempSearch
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CONVERT(NTEXT, URL), 'URL' AS Field
        FROM    #tempSearch
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CONVERT(NTEXT, Description), 'Description' AS Field
        FROM    #tempSearch
    ) As Fields
    GROUP BY Word
    HAVING  COUNT(Word) > 1

   DROP TABLE #tempSearch
```

Comment: Can `sqlserver` be **part** of the `description`? Do you need to break up each field in words?

Comment: Do you have a table set up for the word names you want to search on?

Comment: searching google and found some url for good start  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594430/sql-query-to-count-frequency
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881913/sql-server-function-for-displaying-word-frequency-in-a-column
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/Q_27280249.html
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/SQL-Server-2005/Q_25059415.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975348/ms-sql-query-on-count-occurence-of-words-in-text-column
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641331/problem-counting-item-frequency-on-t-sql?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use UNION to combine your 3 fields into a single column so you can use this to group by. I've also added a few more counts in case you need to drill down as to where the word occurs the most.

```
SELECT  Word, 
        COUNT(Word) AS TotalOccurrences,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Title' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInTitle,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'URL' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInURL,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Description' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInDescription
FROM    (   SELECT  Title AS Word, 'Title' AS Field
            FROM    Users
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  URL, 'URL' AS Field
            FROM    Users
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Description, 'Description' AS Field
            FROM    Users
        ) As Fields
GROUP BY Word
HAVING  COUNT(Word) > 1
```

**EDIT**

I know you have asked about SQL_Server 2005 and 2000, but if you were ever to upgrade to 2008 or later there is a much cleaner solution:

```
SELECT  Word, 
        COUNT(Word) AS TotalOccurrences,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Title' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInTitle,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'URL' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInURL,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Description' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInDescription
FROM    Users
        CROSS APPLY 
        (   VALUES 
                (Title, 'Title'), 
                (URL, 'URL'), 
                (Description, 'Description')
        ) AS T (Word, Field)
GROUP BY Word
HAVING  COUNT(Word) > 1
```

**EDIT 2**

If all your columns are different datatypes you will need to explicitly convert them:

```
SELECT  Word, 
        COUNT(Word) AS TotalOccurrences,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Title' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInTitle,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'URL' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInURL,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Field = 'Description' THEN Word END) AS OccurancesInDescription
FROM    (   SELECT  CONVERT(NTEXT, Title) AS Word, 'Title' AS Field
            FROM    Users
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  CONVERT(NTEXT, URL), 'URL' AS Field
            FROM    Users
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  CONVERT(NTEXT, Description), 'Description' AS Field
            FROM    Users
        ) As Fields
GROUP BY Word
HAVING  COUNT(Word) > 1
```

**EDIT 3**

There is no way around the error you are getting, you cannot group by NTEXT. The best solution I can come up with feels very dirty, and I'm not particularly happy with it...

```
SELECT  COALESCE(Title, URL, Description) AS Word,
        COALESCE(Title.Occurances, 0) + COALESCE(URL.Occurances, 0) + COALESCE(Description.Occurances, 0) AS TotalOccurances,
        COALESCE(Title.Occurances, 0) AS TitleOccurances,
        COALESCE(URL.Occurances, 0) AS URLOccurances,
        COALESCE(Description.Occurances, 0) AS DescriptionOccurances
FROM    (   SELECT  CONVERT(NTEXT, Title) AS Title, COUNT(*) AS Occurances
            FROM    #tempSearch
            GROUP BY Title
        ) AS Title
        FULL JOIN 
        (   SELECT  CONVERT(NTEXT, URL) AS URL, COUNT(*) AS Occurances
            FROM    #tempSearch
            GROUP BY URL
        ) AS URL
            ON URL LIKE Title
        FULL JOIN
        (   SELECT  Description, 1 AS Occurances
            FROM    #tempSearch
        ) AS Description
            ON Description LIKE Title
```

This works, but like I said, it isn't perfect and probably won't perform very well. Strongly consider upgrading to a later version of SQL-Server!

Comment: as per asked this occurrence of word should be more than once.
you should have put having clause as `having count(word) >1`

Comment: i am getting error when executing ur sql because my Title,Description & url field data type is nvarchar and ntext like Title nvarchar(4000),
Description ntext, Url nvarchar(4000) .....so how where to fix in ur sql. plzz help. thanks

Comment: I've added an untested addendum which should hopefully solve the problem.

Comment: i am using sql server 2000 so i can not use nvarchar(max). i can not change ntext or text datatype because Description field will have huge html data.

Comment: still i am getting error...."The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator" after using your updated code.

Comment: my table structure is like CREATE TABLE #tempSearch(
  ID INT,
  Title nvarchar(4000),
  Description ntext,
  Url nvarchar(4000),
  Type char(1))

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of occurrences a word has across three fields using the difference in `LEN()` to account for the word appearing multiple times in the same field:

```
SELECT
    a.wordname,
    SUM(
        ((LEN(b.title) - LEN(REPLACE(b.title, a.wordname, ''))) / LEN(a.wordname)) +
        ((LEN(b.url) - LEN(REPLACE(b.url, a.wordname, ''))) / LEN(a.wordname)) +
        ((LEN(b.description) - LEN(REPLACE(b.description, a.wordname, ''))) / LEN(a.wordname))
    ) AS occurrence
FROM
    (
        SELECT 'sqlserver' AS wordname UNION ALL
        SELECT 'jquery' AS wordname UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ajax' AS wordname
    ) a
CROSS JOIN
    users b
GROUP BY
    a.wordname
ORDER BY
    occurrence DESC
```

If you have a table of wordnames, just put that table name in place of the many `SELECT ... UNION ALL` statements I have put for the sake of example.

Comment: i am getting error when executing ur sql msg is "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator." because my Title,Description & url field data type is nvarchar and ntext like Title nvarchar(4000),
Description ntext, Url nvarchar(4000) .....so how where to fix in ur sql. plzz help. thanks